# What if input needs to be a list in a loop: Any option other than `for`?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

Imagine we have a `foo <- function()` that only takes `A_Named_List_of_One_data.frame` as input. For example: `list(A = data.frame(d = 1:2))`.

Now, imagine we have `A_Named_List_of_Several_data.frames` saved in object `L`. For example:

`L = list(A = data.frame(d = 1:2), B = data.frame(d = 3:5))`.
So to enter `L` elements, we need to loop them into `foo()`.

My understanding is that in this situation ***the only looping option*** is `for` as follows. Are there any other options?

```
  output <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(L)) { output[[i]] <- foo(L[i]) }
  setNames(output, names(L))
```

**ps.** `lapply` enters the elements of `L` into `foo` as a `data.frame` while `foo` needs each element of `L` to be a `A_Named_List_of_One_data.frame`.

Comment: @IanCampbell, `lapply` enters the elements of `L` into `foo` as a `data.frame` while `foo` needs each element of `L` to be a `A_Named_List_of_One_data.frame`.

Comment: @IanCampbell, I think OP is right. `lapply(L, foo)` enters each element of `L` as a data.frame.

Comment: @IanCampbell, names of each element of `L` (in this example `A` & `B`) are needed inside `foo` (NOT SHOWN HERE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for an apply family or related loop, loop over the names and use the fact that `[` on a list returns a list:

```
lapply(names(L), function(nm) foo(L[nm]))
```

Comment: Could we say `lapply` is also faster than `for`?

Comment: Generally, no -- I would not say that. Sometimes it is, sometimes it's not. What I am happy to say is that *unless the operation that `foo()` performs is utterly trivial* the computation time will be dominated by `foo`, not by whatever syntax you choose to call `foo` repeatedly. As long as your `for` loop doesn't do egregious inefficiencies like growing objects inside the loop, it doesn't matter at all whether you use `for` or `lapply` except in the most highly optimized setting.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(names(L), ~ foo(L[.x]))
```